# Add class to DOM collection based on index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var totalItems = $("#resultsList").children().length;
var itemsPerPage = 10;
var pages = Math.ceil(totalItems / itemsPerPage);

function createPagination(pages, page) {
  
  var str = '<ul class="paginatorList">';
  var active;
  var pageCutLow = page - 1;
  var pageCutHigh = page + 1;
  var prevButton = '<li class=\'page-item previous\'><a onclick=\'createPagination(pages, ' + (page - 1) + ');\'>&#60;</a></li>';
  var nextButton = '<li class="page-item next"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, ' + (page + 1) + ');">&#62;</a></li>';
  var firstPage = '<li class="page-item page-item"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, 1);">1</a></li>';
  var ellipseL = '<li class="page-item out-of-range"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, ' + (page - 2) + ');">...</a></li>';
  var ellipseR = '<li class="page-item out-of-range"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, ' + (page + 2) + ');">...</a></li>';
  
  // Show the Previous button only if you are on a page other than the first
  if (page > 1) { str += prevButton; }
  
  // Show all the pagination elements if there are less than 6 pages total
  if (pages < 6) {
    for (let p = 1; p <= pages; p++) {

      active = page == p ? " active" : '';
      var activePage = "<li class=\"page-item" + active + "\"><a onclick=\"createPagination(pages, " + p + ")\">" + p + "</a></li>";
      str += activePage;
    }
  }
  // Use "..." to collapse pages outside of 3 pages range
  else {
    // Show the very first page followed by a "..." at the beginning of the pagination section (after the Previous button)
    if (page > 2) {
      str +=  firstPage;
      if (page > 3) {
          str += ellipseL;
      }
    }
    
    // Determine how many pages to show after the current page index
    (page === 1) ? pageCutHigh += 2 : (page === 2) ? pageCutHigh += 1 : null;
    
    // Determine how many pages to show before the current page index
    (page === pages) ? pageCutLow -= 2 : (page === pages-1) ? pageCutLow -= 1 : null;

    // Output the indexes for pages that fall inside the range of pageCutLow and pageCutHigh 
    for (let p = pageCutLow; p <= pageCutHigh; p++) {
      if (p === 0) { p += 1; }
      if (p > pages) { continue }

      active = (page == p) ? " active" : '';
      var activePage = "<li class=\"page-item" + active + "\"><a onclick=\"createPagination(pages, " + p + ")\">" + p + "</a></li>";
      str += activePage;
    }
    
    // Show the very last page preceded by a "..." at the end of the pagination section (before the Next button)
    if (page < pages-1) {
      if (page < pages-2) {
        str += ellipseR;
      }
      str += '<li class="page-item no"><a onclick="createPagination(pages, pages)">'+pages+'</a></li>';
    }
  }
  // Show the Next button only if you are on a page other than the last
  if (page < pages) { str += nextButton; }
  str += '</ul>';
  
  // Return the pagination string to be outputted
   $("div[id^=pager]").html(str);
   listFilter();
   return str;
}


function listFilter() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);

  function _toConsumableArray(arr) { 
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) { 
      for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
      }
      return arr2;
    } else {
      return Array.from(arr);
    }
  }
  
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('.resultsItem');
  var items = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(list));
  
  var currentPgVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('.page-item.active a').textContent);
  var rangeMax = (currentPgVal) * Number(itemsPerPage) - 1;
  var rangeMin = (rangeMax - Number(itemsPerPage)) + 1;

  for (var item in items) {

    if (item <= rangeMax && item >= rangeMin) {

      var sortDir = $('#filterBtn').find('i[class$=active]').data('sortdir');
      var sortOption = $('#filterOptions').find(':selected').val();

      tinysort('.resultsItem', { order: '' + sortDir, selector: '.' + sortOption });
      items[item].classList.remove("hidden_apa");   
    }
  }
}

// Sort when Icon clicked
$('#filterBtn i').on('click', function () {
  var currentPgVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('.page-item.active a').textContent);
  var rangeMax = (currentPgVal) * Number(itemsPerPage) - 1;
  var rangeMin = (rangeMax - Number(itemsPerPage)) + 1;
  var sortDirection = $('#filterBtn').find('i[class$=active]').data('sortdir');
  var sortOption = $('.filterOptions').find(':selected').val();

  // toggle displaying the two icons, A-Z or Z-A
  $('i[class*=fa-sort-alpha]').toggleClass('hidden active');
  // Hide all the items
  $('.resultsItem').removeClass('active').addClass('hidden');
  // Get the total list  
  var results = document.querySelectorAll('.resultsItem');

  results.forEach(
    function(val, i, listObj) {
      console.log(i, val, this);
   
    if(i >= rangeMin && i <= rangeMax) {
      tinysort('.resultsItem', { order: '' + sortDirection, selector: '.' + sortOption });
      // console.log(i, val);
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
    
});

$(document).ready(function () {

  $("div[id^=pager]").html(createPagination(pages, 1));
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.3.6/tinysort.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filterOptions">

  <select name="filterMenu" class="searchFieldMenu">
    <option value="firstName" data-sortby="first">First Name</option>
    <option value="lastName" data-sortby="last">Last Name</option>
    <option value="cityName" data-sortby="city">City</option>
    <option value="stateName" data-sortby="state">State</option>
  </select>

  <div id="filterBtn">
    <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc active" data-sortdir="asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc hidden_apa" data-sortdir="desc" aria-hidden="false"></i>
  </div>

</div>

<ul id="resultsList">

  <li class="resultsItem">
    <div class="infoBox">
      <h2 class="firstName">Zack</h2>
      <h2 class="lastName">Last Name A</h2>
      <div class="title">Manager</div>
      <div class="company">Walmart</div>
      <div class="location">
        <span class="cityName">Juno</span>,
        <span class="stateName">AK</span>
        <br>United States</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="pagination" id="pager">
  <ul class="paginatorList">
    <li class="page-item active">
      <a onclick="createPagination(pages, 1)">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a onclick="createPagination(pages, 2)">2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**POST UPDATE**

I've included all the relevant JS to allow the snippet to work. There will have to be many results added to the *ul* but I thought that was **TOO** Much code to have displayed.

I'm trying to sort a list of results after an icon is clicked. The expected result should be to hide all the elements in the UL and then unhide the results which meet the condition.

The condition is based on pagination and I'm using [Tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) to sort the list.

So for example, Say you are on page 1 of 3 and each page will only display 10 results. When you click on the Icon to sort the entire list **A-Z** then the results to be displayed are items whose index is within range of that page. So page 1's range is 1 to 10.

I'm close and I'm not able to remove the hidden class on the items that meet the criteria.

I hope I explained this well. I'll add my code so far.

the *REAL* problem I believe is in the NodeList or the **.forEach** Loop.

Comment: It would be a good idea to make your snippet at least working. Questions have to be minimal **but** complete.

Comment: Ok. I was just afraid of posting **A WALL OF CODE** and getting down voted

Comment: There is no `.page-item.active a` at all... Run your snippet to see the errors and make it runnable until it show the issue you're facing.

Comment: Please see that I've included all the relevant code to allow the snippet to work.

Comment: I may be blind... But I still don't see any `.page-item.active a` element in HTML markup. That is the starting point of your `.on()` click handler.

Comment: I had to hard code in the .page-item.active a because this is dynamically created based on the total count of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to slightly modify your code to make it work (before you posted the update).

Then I've made it to sort:

```js
var itemsPerPage = 2;
// Sort when Icon clicked
$('#filterBtn i').on('click', function() {
  var currentPgVal = parseInt(document.querySelector('.page-item.active a').textContent);
  var rangeMax = currentPgVal * Number(itemsPerPage) - 1;
  var rangeMin = (rangeMax - Number(itemsPerPage)) + 1;
  var sortDirection = $('#filterBtn').find('i[class$=active]').data('sortdir');
  var sortOption = $('.filterOptions').find(':selected').val();

  // toggle displaying the two icons, A-Z or Z-A
  $('i[class*="fa-sort-alpha"]').toggleClass('hidden_apa active');

  var results = document.querySelectorAll('.resultsItem');

  // sort
  tinysort(results, {
    order: sortDirection
  })
  
  // Hide out-of-range elements
  .forEach(function(val, i) {
    console.log(i, val.innerText);
    $(val)[(
      i < rangeMin || i > rangeMax ?
      'add' : 'remove'
    ) + 'Class']('hidden_apa');
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden_apa {
  display: none !important;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.3.6/tinysort.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filterBtn">
  <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc hidden_apa" data-sortdir="asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc active" data-sortdir="desc" aria-hidden="false"></i>
</div>

<ul id="resultsList">
  <li class="resultsItem">Item 1</li>
  <li class="resultsItem">Item 2</li>
  <li class="resultsItem hidden_apa">Item 3</li>
  <li class="resultsItem hidden_apa">Item 4</li>
  <li class="resultsItem hidden_apa">Item 5</li>
  <li class="resultsItem hidden_apa">Item 6</li>
</ul>

<div class="pagination" id="pager">
  <span class="page-item active"><a>1</a></span>
  <span class="page-item"><a>2</a></span>
  <span class="page-item"><a>3</a></span>
</div>
```